# Finding two nearest line features to each point

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, proximity, nearest-neighbor

I am using ArcMap

I have hundreds of points as a point shape file and also a polyline feature class as another shape file.

Problem: I need to know two most nearest polyline IDs to each point.

What I tried to do but was not successful:

###### 1- Near tool:

I know that Near tool in the Proximity toolbox of ArcMap software can find the nearest polyline feature to each point.

But what if I need two first nearest features.
I mean if we rank all features in the polyline to each point, I need first two of them (not only the first which is the nearest).

###### 2-  Other ideas

I thought of ideas like buffering each points and then interact the buffer with polyline features to see IDs of intersecting polylines. but I couldn't implement it in the software.

Comment: Generate Near table tool designed for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Generate Near Table` tool can achieve that for you. Make sure you enter `closest count` as 2 considering you want two first nearest features.
The output table will contain the distances and locations of the two nearest polyline features to each point. You can then join the output table to your point layer and use the fields in the table to symbolize the points based on the nearest polyline features.

Refer here for more details:
https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/generate-near-table.htm